# Evaluation of tag [nearest-neighbor] being wrongly used to tag questions about [proximity]/[nearest] & [knn]?

Tags: discussion, tags

*I found [Improving tagging of questions with [nearest-neighbor] and related tags](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4094) addressing the issue exactly, but neither can I follow if there have been any changes made, nor, and more importantly, can I see changes in the tagging behavior.*

As of right now there are [159 questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nearest-neighbor) tagged [nearest-neighbor](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nearest-neighbor) and I assume, only by reading over the titles, that the correct usage of [nearest-neighbor](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nearest-neighbor) has not increased fundamentally to what @raphael counted 3 years ago. To be honest, I myself had been editing/adding the tags in the past to include [nearest-neighbor](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nearest-neighbor) where it is inappropriate, before I realized my mistake...

The [nearest-neighbor](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nearest-neighbor) tag, describing the common **raster resampling algorithm**, is frequently (and wrongly) used to tag questions about spatial relations between vector geometries, **where [proximity](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proximity), [nearest](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nearest) and/or [knn](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knn) is appropriate only**.

Should we evaluate the possibility to change the tags and synonyms to a more intuitive naming/namespacing?

Comment: Do you have any suggestions?  Personally I wouldn't like to see the tag "nearest-neighbor" renamed to anything else, as that tag name fits perfectly with the raster processing task.  So I think we only have two options - 1) improve the tag wiki and excerpt, and 2) actively retag when we see the tag incorrectly used.  Do you have any other solutions to suggest?

Comment: We are always looking for ways to make our tagging more useful but since there is an existing Q&A about this issue the way to progress it is by editing that question to make what it is asking clearer (if needed), editing the answer to make what it is proposing clearer, or adding new answers that make clear proposals for how we can proceed so that they can be voted on by the community.  I'm glad that you have re-raised this, but as much as possible we should avoid creating duplicates so that all answers are gathered in one Q&A.

Comment: @Midavalo I'll add my suggestions in that other post...

Comment: @PolyGeo agreed, let's see what I can do there then...